# Rails 5 Not able to store in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am not able to store the record in the database following is my code

Form Parameters

[image]

Controller

```
def create
    @sales_dailystatus_info = SalesDailystatusInfo.new(sales_dailystatus_info_params)
    @sales_dailystatus_info.user_id = current_user.id
    @project = @sales_dailystatus_info.project
    respond_to do |format|
      if @sales_dailystatus_info.save
        byebug
        format.js{}
        format.html{redirect_to dashboard_project_path(@project)}
      else
        format.js{}
        format.html{render nothing: true}
      end
    end
end

def sales_dailystatus_info_params
    params.require(:sales_dailystatus_info).permit(:user_id, :project_id, :sales_task_id, 
    :task_time, :description)
end
```

Model

```
class SalesDailystatusInfo < ActiveRecord::Base    
     belongs_to :project
     belongs_to :user, optional: true
     belongs_to :sales_task
     validates :user_id, :sales_tasks_id, :task_time, presence: true
end
```

You can see in the screenshot I got rollback while save.

Please help me.

**Edit:**

I have made the change, Now I am iterating the params and remove strong parameters. Following is my code

```
def create
    params[:sales_dailystatus_info].values.each do |sales_dailystatus_info|

    @sales_dailystatus_info = SalesDailystatusInfo.create(
                    project_id: sales_dailystatus_info[:project_id],
                    sales_tasks_id: sales_dailystatus_info[:sales_task_id],
                    task_time: sales_dailystatus_info[:task_time],
                    description: sales_dailystatus_info[:description],
                    user_id: current_user.id
    );  
    byebug       
  end      

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{}
    format.html{render nothing: true}
    end
end
```

still not able to save it. Give me error Sales task must exist.

Comment: Please don't use a screenshot. Include the error message as text in the question itself. Screenshots are hard to read and not searchable.

Comment: What is your ror version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the name of the field.

I change the field sales_tasks_id in sales_daily status_info to sales_task_id.

I need a singular foreign key name instead of plural.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your logs, it looks like your are submitting two SalesDailyStatusInfo:

```rb
{... 'sales_daily_status_info" => { "0" => {"project_id" => ...}, "1" => { "project_id" => ... } } }
```

You don't allow those keys in your params sanitizer, hence the `Unpermitted parameters: :0, :1`. The result is that your don't whitelist any params you submit and the params hash is empty, your model validations fail.

In order for this to work you either need to send only one project at a time or loop through your params to create both `SalesDailyStatusInfo`.

Add the frontend form code to your question if you need further help.

Hope it helps !

Comment: I am looping the params now. But still not able to save it .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your record is not valid. You validate presence of the `user_id` but it's not sent. Instead of rendering nothing try to render `@sales_dailystatus_info.errors.messages`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you validate `:user_id` and put `optional: true` at the same time? Also in your model you have validation of `:sales_task_id` (`belongs_to association default validation on  Ruby on Rails version >= 5.0`) and `:sales_tasks_id`. And in your controller I do see `:sales_tasks_id` key but I do not see `:sales_task_id`, that is why you receive `Sales task must exist error`. Remove unnecessary validations of `:user_id` and `:sales_task_id`, return back strong parameters and everything will be fine

Answer (score 1):

Since you are assigning a `project_id` and a `sales_task_id`, those records must be created before you can create a `sales_dailystatus_info` record. The error you are getting is saying you don’t have a `sales_task` created.